# How to center map to a specific coordinate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mapkit, coordinates

I just want to center the map view to a location but it keeps crashing, here's the code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
```

...

```
CGFloat x = 94.71;
CGFloat y = 6.94;
CLLocationCoordinate2D pointLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(x, y);
[[self map] setCenterCoordinate:pointLocation animated:YES];
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Coordinate +94.70999908, +6.94000006

this code used to work in another app... don't know why it doesn't work... is it because of the data type(CGFloat)?

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0) doesn't crash...

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake parameters are latitude, longitude.  A latitude of 94.71 is out of range (must be from -90 to +90).  You probably want to do `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(y, x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A coordinate is considered invalid if it meets at least one of the following criteria:
>
> Its latitude is greater than 90 degrees or less than -90 degrees.
>
> Its longitude is greater than 180 degrees or less than -180 degrees.

[Core Location Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationFunctions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid)

You can check if the coordinate is valid with `BOOL CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid ( CLLocationCoordinate2D coord );`

Comment: thanks man, didn't knew that about coordinates, I had longitude and latitude all the way around from my feed.